# Sensors that detects and simulate human emotions

Tags: hardware, sensors

Is there any WEARABLE SENSORS available that can simulate human emotions ?

Something like the one in this link https://www.technologyreview.com/s/421316/sensor-detects-emotions-through-the-skin/ (but it doesn't capture many of the human emotions).

I am looking for some WEARABLE sensor that should simulate the level of Anger, Disgust, Fear, Happiness, Sadness, Surprise, Excitement etc of a human at any particular instance. I am NOT looking for emotion detection from Facial expression or voice recognition.

Your Help is much appreciated !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Frauenhofer Shore Software. Frauenhofer creating really great things like mp3. But i think this Software would be really expensive. 
http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/bsy/tech/bildanalyse/shore-gesichtsdetektion.html

Or here is a open source solution:
https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr

Comment: I am not looking for emotion detection from human face/voice. I am looking for wearable sensors that simulates these emotions.